# Cannot change tags of a particular question

Tags: support, editing

I have tried to add the `bashrc` and `bash-profile` tags to [How to fix infinite bash loop (bashrc + bash_profile) when ssh-ing into an ec2 server?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/635893/how-to-fix-infinite-bash-loop-bashrc-bash-profile-when-ssh-ing-into-an-ec2-s/635895#635895) but after clicking "save tag edits" the tags are not applied. I then tried adding the tags together with editing the question body via a normal edit, and even though the body was changed, the tags were not. My browser is Firefox 78.10.0esr, and since it also fails in safe-mode (with add-ons disabled), I'm wondering if it's a bug.

Additionally weird is that I can edit tags normally for other questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the central issue here is that [bashrc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bashrc) and [bash-profile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash-profile) are synonyms to the [bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash) tag, and the Question already has the bash tag, so you don't see any change. See the Synonyms section of: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/bash/info.